# Customize fswebcam file name in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to make the image names generated from fswebcam take a name from a variable in python? The idea is that I have a card swipe system that takes a webcam shot of whoever swipes their card and stores the image in a folder. I want to have the serial number of the card and time be the name of the image generated. Right now, I only found a way to get the time written in the name but not the serial number. Can anyone help me out?

Card Swipe System Code:

```
import datetime
import time
import os
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

t = datetime.datetime.now()

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setwarnings(False)

while True:
    card = raw_input()
    f = open("Laptop Sign Out" + '.txt', 'a')
    f.write("Card Number: " + card[1:10] + " Time: " + t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('fswebcam ~/Desktop/Photos/%H%M%S.jpeg')
    time.sleep(3)

gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: Do you want to save the image with a name that is determined by a variable?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes. The variable would be the card variable (or simply it's just the raw_input() ). So ideally, im hoping the image name would be rawinput_datetime.jpg

Comment: see my answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the appropriate text, in this case use format.

```
os.system('fswebcam ~/Desktop/Photos/{}_{}.jpeg'.format(card, t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

complete code:

```
import datetime
import time
import os
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setwarnings(False)

while True:
    card = raw_input()
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    f = open("Laptop Sign Out" + '.txt', 'a')
    f.write("Card Number: " + card[1:10] + " Time: " + t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('fswebcam ~/Desktop/Photos/{}_{}.jpeg'.format(card, t.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")))
    time.sleep(3)

gpio.cleanup()
```

*Note: I have moved the location of the variable t since if it is inside the loop it will never be updated.*